# Auto show item in recyclerview to another recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I making an app for tablet so it will have two recyclerview on one activity. What I want to do is when I click an item on first recyclerview, the item information will show automatically on another recyclerview as a list. But what actually my coding do is when I click the item, the item not show automatically on another recyclerview. When I exit the app and relaunch back, finally show the item on another recyclerview.

Actually I have tried put notifysetdatachanged but it still the same.

This MainActivity.java

```
private void displayItemPurchased() {
    itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursorItemPurchased = myDb.getItemPurchased();
    while (cursorItemPurchased.moveToNext()) {
        String itemId = cursorItemPurchased.getString(1);
        String itemDescription = cursorItemPurchased.getString(2);
        int itemQty = cursorItemPurchased.getInt(3);
        Double itemAmt = cursorItemPurchased.getDouble(4);
        String itemTimestamp = cursorItemPurchased.getString(5);

        Product_Item item = new Product_Item();
        item.setItemDescription(itemId);
        item.setItemDescription(itemDescription);
        item.setItemQty(itemQty);
        item.setItemAmt(itemAmt);
        item.setItemTimestamp(itemTimestamp);

        itemList.add(item);
    }

    adapterItemsList = new AdapterItemsList(getApplication(), itemList, cursorItemPurchased);
    rvList.setAdapter(adapterItemsList);
    adapterItemsList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This AdapterItem.java

```
public class AdapterItem extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterItem.MyViewHolder> {

    private int row_index = -1;

    private ArrayList<Product_Item> itemsList;
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    //SQLite
    DatabaseHelper myDb;

    public AdapterItem(Context ctx, ArrayList<Product_Item> itemsList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_items_list, parent, false);

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Product_Item item = itemsList.get(position);
        final String id = item.getItemId();
        final String name = item.getItemDescription();
        final int qty = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtQty.getText().toString());
        final Double amt = item.getItemAmt();
        final String timestamp =  item.getItemTimestamp();

        holder.itemId_tv.setText(id);
        holder.itemName_tv.setText(name);
        holder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        holder.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                row_index = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                myDb.insertItemPurchased(id, name, qty, amt, timestamp);
            }
        });

        if (row_index == position) {
            holder.layoutQTY.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.layoutQTY.setAnimation(holder.fromBottom);
        } else {
            holder.layoutQTY.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Animation fromBottom, fromTop;
        LinearLayout layoutQTY;
        TextView itemId_tv, itemName_tv,txtQty;
        ImageButton btnPlus,btnMinus;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            fromBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,R.anim.qtyfrombottom);
            fromTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,R.anim.qtyfromtop);

            itemId_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemId);
            itemName_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            layoutQTY = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutQTY);
            txtQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
            btnPlus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
            btnMinus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        }
    }
}
```

And This AdapterItemList

```
public class AdapterItemsList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterItemsList.ItemListViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Product_Item> itemsList;
    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public AdapterItemsList(Context ctx, ArrayList<Product_Item> itemsList, Cursor cursor){
        mContext = ctx;
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        mCursor = cursor;
    }

    public class ItemListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView nameText;
        public TextView countText;
        public TextView priceText;

        public ItemListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemList);
            countText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
            priceText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPriceItem);

        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_pay_list_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new ItemListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product_Item item = itemsList.get(position);
        final String id = item.getItemId();
        final String name = item.getItemDescription();
        final int qty = item.getItemQty();
        final Double amt = item.getItemAmt();
        final String timestamp =  item.getItemTimestamp();

        holder.nameText.setText(name);
        holder.countText.setText(String.valueOf(qty));
        holder.priceText.setText(String.valueOf(amt));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }

    public void swapCursor (Cursor newCursor){
        if (mCursor != null){
            mCursor.close();
        }

        mCursor = newCursor;

        if (newCursor != null){
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add item to recylcerview , in your adding adapter do this : 
 - Create a method :

```
public void addSingleProduct(Product_Item productItem){
   itemsList.add(productItem);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But you need also to remove it from the other adapter where you already have it 
Create a method :

```
public void removeItem(Product_Item productItem){
   itemsList.remove(productItem)
   int position = itemsList.indexOf(productItem);
   notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

And than call the methods in where your adapter instance is , in your case the MainActivity.

Comment: why i must remove?actually i want to make just like adding item to a cart but not really to cart..to the list directly in the same page..when i click item in first recyclerview the item goes to another recyclerview but item still remain in first item..my case is the item is add to another recyclerview but not on the spot..it add everytime i relaunch app.

Comment: if you want to add it somewhere else and remove it from your current view , there you have for both adding and removing